# How do I fix a Raspberry Pi 4 that isn't displaying anything?

Tags: pi-4, display, retropie, lcd

The problem first started when I tried to change the orientation of display for retro pi. Before, the orientation was vertical. So I tried to change the resolution options in "Raspi-config" to make it horizontal. I put the resolution as "480x640 4:3" because I was pretty sure that was the resolution of the LCD screen I was using. (The LCD screen is attached to the Raspberry Pi and is 4 inches) It turns out it was 480x800, and now nothing will display. I tried to reinstall retro pi with a newer version (4.7.1) and that didn't change the display problem. The last Idea I had was to hook it up to a TV, so I used a USB C hook up, and it STILL didn't display anything. Then I tried using an HDMI hook up instead, and nothing happened. What sucks is that the LCD screen and the other TV never said "No signal" so I know the application still booted, I just couldn't see anything at all.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me. This is my first project involving a raspberry pi.

UPDATE: It now displays on a monitor, but not the LCD screen yet.

Comment: I don't have any experience with retro pie, but wouldn't it be easier to just reinstall it?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but because the setting change was in Rasp Pi config, now it won't display anything at all, unless I hook it up to a monitor.

Comment: I think he means to re-install using a "fresh" (a.k.a. default) image - not one you may have dorked up.

Comment: What do you mean by default image?

Comment: @Seamus is correct - it would be the easiest to burn the original retro pie image onto it. You may need a Linux computer to copy data off the SD card before you reimage.

Comment: You also say that it displays on a monitor - why not just plug your Pi in and change the resolution via raspi-config??? Then reboot and unplug the monitor and plug the TFT back in.

Comment: `default image`: unmodified - as you downloaded it initially before things were hosed up.

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino That's what I did yesterday, and then I changed the resolution settings to "recommended", that didn't work, so then I tried to change the resolution to whatever the LCD display was, but the option wasn't there.

Comment: @Seamus well the image was off the retro pie site, and I didn't do anything to it. I just installed it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the LCD you bought? Maybe you skipped a step? Anyways, I would try redoing everything at this point.